# JQUERY is running twice in this ScrollTo Highlight code snippet?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Any ideas given the code below why the highlight is being triggered to run twice? I confirmed it's running twice using alerts which fire more than once. See anything wrong here?

```
//Scroll to the Anchor in the URL, if there is one
var destination = $(document.location.hash).offset().top;
$("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({ scrollTop: destination-20}, 500, function() {
// Animation complete.
$(document.location.hash).effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run your selector in the Firebug console.  I'm fairly certain it will be returning two items. Run "$("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").size()" in the console and you'll see what I mean.   On pretty much any webpage you're going to get a match for html:not(:animated) as well as for body:not(:animated).  The comma in your selector means "Selects the combined results of all the specified selectors." [API Document is here](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).  And the call to animate will act on each element in the wrapped set that is returned.  Maybe something else is going on, but I would check the size of the wrapped set first.